# WHERE_IN query with a composite key?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table with a two-part composite key, and 4 records, like the following:

```
KEY_PART_1 KEY_PART_2
A          1
B          1
C          2
C          3
```

I want to write some dynamic SQL to select only the records B,1 and C,2 using a "WHERE IN" clause, *without* selecting A,1 or C,3.

Is there some way to do this without a temp table?

Not that it matters, but we are currently using Oracle, and hoping to move to PostgreSQL soon.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This syntax works for Oracle and PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE (key_part_1, key_part_2) IN ( ('B',1), ('C',2) );
```

Comment: Don't know if Oracle has the same problem, but in MySQL if you use this syntax it won't make use of the index.

Comment: Do you know how would you do this using ODP.NET?

Comment: @Barmar in an SQL query [the order in which the composing keys are used matters](https://sqlhints.com/2017/10/01/does-the-order-of-columns-in-a-composite-index-matters-tip-3-sql-server-101-performance-tuning-tips-and-tricks/) and it affects exactly whether relying on composite indexes or not.

Comment: @Kamafeather That's only relevant if the `WHERE` clause uses a subset of the columns in the key, but this query uses the entire key. But when I tested it, MySQL still didn't use the key.

Comment: I could not find this syntax in documentation of PostgreSQL. Most near is https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR with addition of https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#COMPOSITE-TYPE-COMPARISON, but it looks very indirect. Does anyone knows more direct description of this syntax support?

Comment: Can confirm that this syntax works for sqlite as well.

Answer (score 6):

Following @Justin Cave's answer, here is a small test case to show that **Oracle** would do an **INDEX RANGE SCAN** followed by an **INLIST ITERATOR** for the following **filter predicate**:

```
WHERE (key_part_1, key_part_2) IN ( ('B',1), ('C',2) )
```

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(key1 VARCHAR2(1), key2 NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('A', 1);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('B', 1);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('C', 2);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('C', 3);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

A **composite index** on **key1 and key2**:

```
SQL> CREATE INDEX t_idx ON t(key1, key2);

Index created.

SQL>
```

**Gather stats:**

```
SQL> EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('LALIT', 'T');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**Execute the query:**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t
  2  WHERE (key1, key2) IN ( ('B',1), ('C',2) );

K       KEY2
- ----------
B          1
C          2

SQL>
```

So, it gives the correct output.

Let's see the **explain plan**:

**Case# 1** Key-value pair in the same order of the index. Leading key in the lead.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2301620486

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |       |     2 |    10 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  INLIST ITERATOR  |       |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| T_IDX |     2 |    10 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access(("KEY1"='B' AND "KEY2"=1 OR "KEY1"='C' AND "KEY2"=2))

14 rows selected.
```

**Case# 2** Key-value pair in opposite order of the index. Leading key in reverse.

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM t
  2  WHERE (key2, key1) IN ( (1, 'B'), (2, 'C') );

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2301620486

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |       |     2 |    10 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  INLIST ITERATOR  |       |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| T_IDX |     2 |    10 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access(("KEY1"='B' AND "KEY2"=1 OR "KEY1"='C' AND "KEY2"=2))

14 rows selected.
```

In either cases, **Oracle uses the index**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you want something like this which works for almost all RDBMSs:

```
select KEY_PART_1, KEY_PART_2 from your_table where KEY_PART_1='B' and KEY_PART_2 = '1'
UNION
select KEY_PART_1, KEY_PART_2 from your_table where KEY_PART_1='C' and KEY_PART_2 = '2'
```

Comment: Just a note, though this query would give the desired output. However, this query will go for 2 index range scans. Justin's query would do a single index range scan. So, performance wise, Justin's query is better.