# WHERE IN with composite keys and wildcards (postgres)

Tags: postgresql

As an extension to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479891/where-in-query-with-a-composite-key), is it possible to incorporate wildcards with postgres?

E.g. Something like this (note the wildcard to select all entries where `key_part_1` has a value of 'C'):

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE (key_part_1, key_part_2) IN ( ('B',1), ('C',?) );
```

Is this possible, and if so, what's the syntax?

Comment: `WHERE (key_part_1, key_part_2) IN ( ('B',1), ('C', key_part_2) );` Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same column in `IN` clause(if both columns are not nullable):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE (key_part_1, key_part_2) IN ( ('B',1), ('C',key_part_2) );
```

So for second  value pair only `key_part_1='C'` will be used because `key_part_2=key_part_2` is always true.

```
WHERE (key_part_1, key_part_2) IN ( ('B',1), ('C',key_part_2) );
<=>
WHERE (key_part_1='B' AND key_part_2 = 1)
   OR (key_part_1='C' AND key_part_2 = key_part_2);
```

---

If columns can be nullable you can wrap it with `COALESCE(column_name, value)` like:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE (key_part_1, COALESCE(key_part_2,-1)) IN ( ('B',1), 
                                                 ('C',COALESCE(key_part_2,-1)) );
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c4e9a/2/0)**</kbd>

Note that value used in `COALESCE` should be distinct for actual data to avoid colisions.

Comment: This will fail if key_part_2 happens to be NULL. (`NULL =  NULL` is false in SQL)

Answer (score 1):

If key_part_2 can be anything, there is no need to test it.

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE (key_part_1, key_part_2) IN ( ('B',1) )
    OR  key_part_1 IN('C' )
    ;
```