# Create a JPQL (or Criteria) using a list of map (key, value) as parameter with OR condition

Tags: hibernate, jpql, criteria

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a query a JPQL that I could pass a list of map (key and value). Parameter example for the query:

```
Map<String, String> personCodeAndDocumentNumber;
personCodeAndDocumentNumber.put("123", "123123123");
personCodeAndDocumentNumber.put("456", "ASD45345");
```

And pass this values to find them, generating a SQL like this:

```
SELECT p FROM person p
JOIN document d ON d.pessoa_id = p.id
WHERE (p.code = '123' AND d.number = '123123123') 
OR (p.code = '456' AND d.number = 'ASD45345')
```

This map can have a lot of values.

One [possible alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29479935/2387977) could be using `IN` clause, but I think that this only work with columns on the same table. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE (key_part_1, key_part_2) IN ( ('B',1), ('C',2) );
```

The only way that I know to do this is concatenating the JPQL strings and adding the values directly on the JPQL, but **I will be vulnerable to a SQL injection** doing this:

```
String s = "SELECT p FROM Person p "; 
+ "JOIN p.document d ";
+ "WHERE ";

for (Entry<String, String> entry = personCodeAndDocumentNumber.entrySet()) {
    s += "(p.code = '" + entry.getKey() + "' AND d.number = '" + entry.getValue() + "') ";
    s += "OR ";
}
```

I know that I can handle the entry values to not be vulnerable to SQL Injection using some `escape` method, but I'm hoping to find a better way to accomplish this. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can only have perhaps 256 or so max parameters in a list. You need to break the query up into multiple queries and combine the results.

Comment: @K.Nicholas, I'm having a performance problem doing multiple queries. This is why I'm trying this strategy now. But I will not have more than 100 parameters in the application.

Comment: I think that it is really a good use case for the criteria API.

Comment: The criteria api will have the same issue, it will create a query with many parameters and crash. I had the same issue. If I ran multiple individual queries it was slow. The list had maybe 400 items in it. I broke it up into 4 - 100 item queries, was fine. However, my query was "where id in :idList" and not as complicated as a bunch of OR's. A bunch of OR's is a bad idea. See if you can rethink that.

Comment: Btw, if you have a join you need a distinct: "select distinct p from Person p left join fetch p.pessoa where …"

Comment: Anyway, can't you just put "or" or "||" in jpql? If not, then davidxxx is right, use CriteriaApi.

Comment: The actual OP question seems the SQL risk and the code quality. In its comment, it is said that no more than 100 parameters can be passed. But I admit that it stays a bad idea to pass so many parameters. A possible alternative would be  to use a temporary state in a table of the database that will contain the list of the ids of the row to make match in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @davidxxx and K.Nicholas, thank you for the contributions. I will think at another strategy before continue with this idea